# IndexError does not occur while debugging

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, debugging, compiler-errors

I have some python code and every time I just run it (through Visual Studio Code), I get an IndexError at the end when I iterate through a list.
However, when I try to debug the code to find out what went wrong, the code works just fine and I get the correct result, and exactly what I expect - and no error. I already tried to clear all caches, and even went so far as to change to a different computer to try it - just for it to occur on that other machine too.

To illustrate what I am doing, I have an array of integers, e.g. `[0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2]`, where the integer denotes which *Job* an *Operation* belongs to, and the number of occurrence determines which *operation* of the *job* it is. E.g., the `0` at index `0` is Operation `0` of Job `0`, while the `0` at index `2` is Operation `1` of Job `0`.

```
    jobs = []
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        if sequence[i] not in jobs:
            jobs.append(sequence[i])

    next_operations = [0] * len(jobs)

    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        job = sequence[i]
        operation = next_operations[job]
        next_operations[job] += 1
```

When I run the script the line `operation = next_operations[job]` is causing the Error `IndexError: list index out of range`.

As already mentioned, I tried debugging the code - but the issue does no longer occur. The error happens *every* time when I run the code normally, but *never* during debugging. I reset everything, restarted the computer to make sure there is no weird cache, changed to a different computer, even switched python versions (3.11, 3.10, 3.9) but all leads to the same result.
I'm assuming (more like hoping) that there is some obvious config I messed up somehow, but I can not find anything so far.
Anyone had a similar situation?

Comment: Are you "skipping" any values in `sequence`, E.g., `[0, 1, 3]`?
If not can you provide the value of `sequence` when you are getting the exception?

Comment: *What problem are you trying to solve?* Error is caused when you have gaps in the sequence, e.g. `[0, 1, 2, 3, 5]` or not starting at 0, e.g `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Root cause is trying to use an **element, not index** `job = sequence[i]` as index into a list that is **count *(zero based)* of unique elements long** `next_operations = [0] * len(jobs)`.

Comment: what is `next_operations = [0] * len(jobs)`? Because this will produce a resultant list `[0,0,0]. And in the next step, when you say `operation = next_operations[job]`, operation will be 0 for any index whether it is 0, 1 or 2

Comment: the values in sequence never skip a value, the values in sequence are job ids - they are valid in all examples I tried, otherwise I wouldn't be able to use the jobs as indices at all (and it would also fail while debugging) - the issue is not within the values in the sequence @DanielB

Comment: When I run your code, `next_operation` results in `[2, 2, 3]`. Is this the wanted output? If yes, there must be something wrong with your execution settings.

Comment: Try running your code from command line, like `py main.py` and print the results.

Comment: Yes, I tried running it from command line multiple times, the code does what it is supposed to do, as I can see during debugging. I do not think that the issue is in the logic of the code - and that's the issue. I am currently re-installing everything from python itself to VSCode in the hopes that whatever messed up setting I have will be reset @LoukasPap

Comment: Hi dhutter92, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out the answer to this one, though I'm still not sure what exactly caused it.
After reinstalling everything (including Python), it worked again - I had multiple Python versions installed (required for different projects), and at some point a change I made to one of them must have messed up something they shared for the other one.
Re-installing fixed the issue, the code was already correct as it was.

Answer (score 0):

If `sequence` contains an element that is greater than or equal to the number of unique elements in `sequence`, this will result in an `IndexError`.

You could try to use the following codes to avoid this problem:

```
jobs = []
next_operations = {}

for i in range(len(sequence)):
    job = sequence[i]
    if job not in jobs:
        jobs.append(job)
        next_operations[job] = 0

    operation = next_operations[job]
    next_operations[job] += 1
```

Comment: sequence is guaranteed to have correct values since they can only be the job ids - they never skip an integer - also in that case the error would occur during debugging too. I resolved the issue by now after I literally just reinstalled everything, the code was already correct, as mentioned above it was some issue with the configuration of the run environment